# Using Neural Network as loss for another Neural Network in pytorch

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, loss

I struggle to implement the following in Pytorch Lightning. I have two neural networks, say *f,g* with *g* is pretrained and *f* has to be trained from scratch. The loss of *f* is defined for a training pair *(x,y)* as *l1=mse(g(f(x)),g(y))*. Here *x,y* are 1D arrays (time-domain signals) but it really doesn't matter for this question.
Now the loss can be equivalently defined by extending *f* by *g*, called this network *h* and freezing all layers in *g*. Then *mse(h(x), g(y))* is the same loss as *l1*. But when I write, before training:

```
    g.eval()
    for param in g.parameters():
        param.requires_grad = False
```

and try to train my network, then I get an error

```
RuntimeError: cudnn RNN backward can only be called in training mode
```

This makes of course only sense. So my question is, how can I use *g* as a loss function that is fully backpropatable. I need this property, since I want to compute the gradients *dg(f(x))/dx*.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the entire question. But, have you tried `detach`ing the output of `g` from the network prior to backprop? This way PyTorch can't actually attempt to backprop past the detachment point..?

Comment: But in that case in is just not possible to compute any gradients in *g* ? To clarify: I want to compute the gradients in *g*, so that I can compute *dg(f(x)/x*. Once I computer that quantity, I can update the weights in *f*. I DO NOT want to update any parameters/weights in *g*.

Comment: Can you show the code where you infer `g(f(x))` and `g(y)`?

Comment: What if your optimizers only include the parameters of `f`? In this way even if gradients of `g` are computed, they are not used to update `g`.

Comment: How do you make sure, that your optimizers only updates parameters of f and not g?. I think I found a solution: You must remove g.eval() and freeze all parameters with param.requires_grad=False for g